# How To Connect Sequelize Node To Amazon RDS Postgres

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, sequelize.js, amazon-rds

I'm having trouble connecting sequelize to Amazon RDS Postgres DB.

Below is my connection String:

```
const dbConfig = new Sequelize(database, username, password, {
  host: host,
  ssl: true,
  dialect: "postgres",
  logging: console.log,
});
```

This prints the ff error:

```
SequelizeConnectionError: password authentication failed for user "USER01"
```

This **USER01** is my local postgres username. I don't even know why its trying to connect to my local server.

If I provide the ff connection string:

```
const dbConfig = new sequelize.Sequelize(database, username, password, {
  host: host,
  ssl: true,
  dialect: "postgres",
  dialectOptions: {
    ssl: "Amazon RDS"
  },
  logging: console.log,
});
```

I get the ff error:

```
C:\Users\USER01\Desktop\myproject\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:85
        if ('key' in self.ssl) {
                  ^

TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'key' in Amazon RDS
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\USER01\Desktop\myproject\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:85:19)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:422:26)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:295:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:271:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:212:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:186:23)
```

NOTE: The connection strings I'm proving are my Amazon RDS connection details.

Answer (score 1):

```
dialectOptions: {
    ssl: {
       {rejectUnauthorized: false},
    }
}
```

Please try with this

Comment: It's not about connecting with SSL but how to connect because I don't have the SSL certs and keys. Even with the SSL property removed I still can't connect to the DB.